# Running git commands from post-receive hook

Tags: git, bash

Explaining why I want to do this is complicated, but what I would like to do is to equip a particular git repository with a post-receive hook that does the following:

1. Move to a test directory
2. Clone the project that was just updated.
3. Checkout a specific branch.
4. Do some tests

The post-receive code looks like this (simplified): let "repo" be the name of the git repository, let "testdir" be the name of a sibling directory, initially empty, and let "dev" be the name of the branch.

```
cd ../testdir
git clone --local ../repo .
git checkout dev
```

However, when the code in the script gets to "git checkout", git responds with "fatal: not a git repository: '.'"

I have no idea why git thinks "testdir" isn't a git repository. If I run that commands from a command line (rather than from within post-receive), then they work correctly. I don't know why the behavior would be different from within post-receive. Any ideas?

Comment: That was a typo in my original post. That's not the problem. I cloned into the current directory, "testdir".

Comment: If you do
cd ../testdir
git clone --local ../repo .
(note the ".")
then you are still in testdir, and that contains a clone of the repository.
then you are still in the same directory

Comment: Whoops, missed the trailing `.`. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You need to unset `GIT_DIR` in your `post-receive` hook.  The problem is that at the time your hook script runs, `GIT_DIR=.`, which after your cd and clone operation is no longer useful.

I set up a local test environment, and when my `post-receive` script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ../testdir
git clone --local ../upstream.git .
git checkout dev
```

I get this:

```
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

But if I unset the `GIT_DIR` variable:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset GIT_DIR
cd ../testdir
git clone --local ../upstream.git .
git checkout dev
```

Everything works.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Here's another related question that hopefully has a related answer. In my experiment, I do a hard reset and then run some cleanup code. Specifically, I run

`git reset --hard HEAD^`
`git for-each-ref --format='delete %(refname)' refs/original | git update-ref --stdin`
`git reflog expire --expire=now --all`
`git gc --aggressive --prune=now`

If I run that code from a command line, it has the effect of removing the last commit from the git history. But running it from within post-receive doesn't have the same effect (on garbage collection, anyway).

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a similar variable that would effect how garbage collection, reflog and prune work?